# Modify Column View

Tags: view, folder, file

I have a library containing folders, sub-folders and PDF files.
Is it possible to display a column only visible for PDF files? I don't want this column to be visible when only the folders are displayed

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible OOB.

To meet this requirement you can setup metadata navigation, when folders structure will be presented on the left pane (**circle #2** on the screenshot). This solution has a lot of other benefits, but is not available on all SharePoint versions and editions. Consult the [documentation](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Configure-metadata-navigation-for-a-list-or-library-a8ddfcd1-a486-4e0f-b1b1-f10ca79fa9bc).

[image]